# Can someone give sample SOAP WSDL webservice with wsdl file

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I need to create soap server with wsdl file and allow my clients to use webservice with soap clients with non wsdl mode.

I would really appreciate if anyone can post sample working webservice code. I am having problems with non wsdl soap client. No one on stackoverflow could answer my previous questions, so I am now asking for sample code.

Comment: I'll have to dig through my old code to get u a sample, but i used the YII framework to create a soap server and generate my wsdl. It easy enough, but i'll see if i can find some time to post the code.

Comment: @Rob If you have some experience with webservices, Can you please have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20366539/can-i-use-soap-client-without-wsdl-to-connect-to-web-service-that-has-been-creat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lets go, This is a sample hello world soap web service program, Go through the program,  if u doesn't understand anything ask me ...

actually, there are few styles available in soap binding, here i have used the rpc

    package com.kowthal.ws;

    import javax.jws.WebMethod;
    import javax.jws.WebService;
    import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
    import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Style;

    //Service Endpoint Interface
    @WebService
    @SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC)
    public interface HelloWorld{

        @WebMethod String getHelloWorldAsString(String name);
     }


This is for implementation panel, the returned value will be mapped in soap webservice call
   package com.kowthal.ws;

    import javax.jws.WebService;

    //Service Implementation
    @WebService(endpointInterface = "com.kowthal.ws.HelloWorld")
    public class HelloWorldImpl implements HelloWorld{

        @Override
        public String getHelloWorldAsString(String name) {
            return "soap done by " + name;
        }

    }

this is the endpoint, here i had bind the data with specific url please note down the packages

    package com.kowthal.endpoint;

    import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;
    import com.kowthal.ws.HelloWorldImpl;

    //Endpoint publisher
    public class HelloWorldPublisher{

        public static void main(String[] args) {
           Endpoint.publish[juz tag]("http://localhost:9988/ws/hello", new HelloWorldImpl());
        }

    }

This one is for client side communication

    package com.kowthal.client;

    import java.net.URL;
    import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
    import javax.xml.ws.Service;
    import com.kowthal.ws.HelloWorld;

    public class HelloWorldClient{
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     URL url = new URL[juz tag]("http://localhost:9988/ws/hello?wsdl");
           QName qname = new QName[juz tag]("http://ws.kowthal.com/", "HelloWorldImplService");
                Service service = Service.create(url, qname);
                HelloWorld hello = service.getPort(HelloWorld.class);
                System.out.println(hello.getHelloWorldAsString("kowthal"));
            }

        }

after that using this url u can retrive the xml data
[juz tag]"http://localhost:9988/ws/hello?wsdl"
```